# Paleogeographic Map

Tags: geology, paleogeography

How do you construct a paleogeographic map with given sedimentary structures as guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

While we're certainly not going to do your homework for you (and we couldn't anyway, because the map is not legible in the photo you provided), this looks like a fun exercise and a chance to express your creativity.

Your teacher has asked you to draw some paleo geographic features on a map given some sedimentary features that have been plotted for you.

Try to think of how those features are laid down in a sedimentary environment. Are they indicative of land? rivers? ocean?

For example, if there's a point that shows sandstone, there must have been sand laid down in the past.

Then, picture how the features that your teacher wants would have contributed to that deposition, and where they would have been in relation to one another while the sediments were being deposited.

Finally, you can draw the features on the map in between or around the provided points, based upon how you decided that would happen.